# How do I put two label together?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am doing a UI and using tkinter to establish it. As seen in the picture below I want the two labels above equally.

[image: Picture]

This is the code that I have written for creating this.

```
Player1 = "Terry"  
Player2 = "David"
player1 = tk.Label(top,
                   text=Player1,
                   font="Times 45",
                   fg="white",
                   bg="#0000FF")
player1.pack(side=TOP, padx=10,pady=10,  anchor=NW)
player2 = tk.Label(top,
                   text=Player2,
                   font="Times 45",
                   fg="white",
                   bg="#FF0000")
player2.pack(side=TOP, padx=10,pady=10,anchor=N)
```

I tried to adjust it using anchor and side but form reason I cant make the other label go up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`grid` is an alternative to `pack` that might be easier in this case. Essentially, your interface is divided into a grid of rows and columns, and locations of objects are specified by their row and column location. Your code might look like this:

```
player1.grid(row=0, column=0)
player2.grid(row=0, column=1)
```

---

If you'd rather stick with `pack`, you just need to specify `side` as `'left'`/`'right'`:

```
player1.pack(side='left')
player2.pack(side='left`)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are expecting the output as below, then here is your code.
[image]

```
Player1 = "Terrry"  
Player2 = "David"
player1 = tk.Label(top,
                   text=Player1,
                   font="Times 45",
                   fg="white",
                   bg="#0000FF")
player1.pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=10,pady=10, anchor=tk.NW)
player2 = tk.Label(top,
                   text=Player2,
                   font="Times 45",
                   fg="white",
                   bg="#FF0000")
player2.pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=10,pady=10, anchor=tk.N)
```

Instead of passing 'TOP' to the 'side' attribute you could pass 'LEFT' to achieve this. Also, you could either use 'NW' or 'N' to the 'anchor' attribute.